# How to validate whether a regex itself is valid or not?

Tags: javascript, regex

In JS, is there a regex to check the given regex itself is valid or not?

Comment: With that said, just...compile the regex.

Comment: If a regular expression is syntactically incorrect, you'll get an error from the parser or from the RegExp constructor.

Comment: why not just use ```try..catch```

Comment: @vlaz I too tried this answer, but it seems not valid for javascript.

Comment: I actually recommend starting off with a tool like [regex101](http://www.regex101.com), which can be a nice sandbox in which to test things.

Comment: @vlaz Your link to duplicate question leads to general `regex` question, but not to `javascript` one.

Comment: @VladimirKovpak the second most voted answer is still relevant - just try to initiate a regex and see if there is a problem. The most voted (and accepted) answer is a very good demonstration of *why you don't want to validate regex with regex*. It's too complex and very hard to maintain. The fact that it doesn't work in JS by copy/pasting is nothing more than a very practical example of that. You can change it, if you want - there are suggestions for how in that same answer. And maybe you have enough regex grammar in JS to have a regex for validating regexes but, again do you want to?

Comment: @VladimirKovpak and I actually see now that your very own answer is not much different from the second answer in the dupe. You are using `try...catch` exactly as advised there.

Comment: @vlaz Yes, true. And I like accepted answer from your link! But 
my worries related to fact that OP may be perplexed why js related question duplicates with non-js related question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap you code into `try-catch` block, like this:

```
try {
  re = new RegExp(/(.*/); // or re = /(.*/;
} catch (err) {
  console.log("ERR:", err);
}
```

Result:

```
ERR: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(.*/: Unterminated group
```

Comment: Your `new RegExp` is a bit pointless, unless you are going to pass a string instead.   just doing `re = /(.*/;` would have done the same.

Comment: @Keith Yep, completely agree! But I decide to use this one because it feels like regex must be provided from outside world.